How to quantify the impact of tokenizer output changes on text encoder embeddings?
In natural language processing, generating text embeddings involves two key modules: the tokenizer and the text encoder. The tokenizer converts text into a token vector, which the encoder then uses to produce the final text embedding. The quality of the text embedding is highly dependent on the token vector. For instance, slight variations in similar sentences like 'A spoon on a cup' versus 'A spoon in a cup' can lead to significant differences in the resulting embeddings, often with changes affecting one or a few elements in the tokenizer output. I am interested in quantifying how such changes in the tokenizer output affect the spread of variations in the text encoder's embeddings.
While metrics like cosine similarity and Euclidean distance are commonly used to measure differences in embeddings, they do not directly capture the spread of variability introduced by changes at the tokenizer level. Are there any established or novel metrics that effectively measure the impact of tokenizer variations on the spread of encoder embeddings? What specific approaches or techniques have others found useful in similar contexts?
